# Mysql-server-8.0 fails to install due to existing mysql service in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I just removed mariadb-server from my Ubuntu 20.04 (MATE). The service does not seem to be running any more, given that mysql client is unable to establish a connection to the localhost server.

Then, I tried installing mysql-server-8.0:

```
roman@TestPlatform:/home/roman$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-8.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-8.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1.261 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1.465 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 271442 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new mysql-server-8.0 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried searching for mysqld with ps command, but nothing was detected. Also tried:

```
systemctl stop mysql
systemctl stop mysqld
systemctl stop mariadb
systemctl stop mariadbd
systemctl stop mysql-service
```

But none of those detected a running service to be stopped.

Any help with this?

Comment: How about `sudo killall mysqld`?

Comment: @Jos "mysqld: No process found"

Comment: In that case, there is probably a  `.pid` file left in your `/var/lib/mysql` directory. Try `sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/*.pid`.

Comment: @Jos I don't even have a mysql folder in /var/lib/, since I have already tried using rm -rf over /var/lib/mysql and other mysql folders to try to fix the issue